# Nextjs Image component loading slow on map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, optimization, next.js

When i **use map** the images render slow on localhost. However, when I dont use map it loads quickly.

I used a variety of props from Image component but none seem to fix this issue.

However, after all images rendered and I hit the refresh button they load fast.

This is quite confusing. **Is there any way to load images quickly upon first page visit?**

```
import React from 'react';
import Image from 'next/image';
import styles from './Peoples.module.scss';
export const Peoples = () => (
  <>
    {[...Array(10)].map((x, i) => (
      <div className={styles.team_img_container} key={i}>
        <Image
          style={{ height: 100, width: 100 }}
          src={`/people/${i + 1}.webp`}
          alt="Picture of the author"
          width={100}
          height={100}
          // unoptimized={true}
          // loading="eager"
          priority={true}
          // quality={70}
        />
      </div>
    ))}
  </>
);

export default Peoples;
```

Comment: Have you tried a normal `for` loop or `while` loop instead of `Array.map()`?

Comment: @Edper I just tried it with  a for loop and pushing to an array and rendering the array with return <div>{array}</div>

Comment: Ok. But why the array? When it seems you just need it as an incremental index? Thus a for or while loop without an array would be fine. Unless you have some part of your code that you did not show. But honestly, I don't think it would make a difference. Probably the size of your image could be the problem. With 10 of them that would obviously slows the loading of those images.

Comment: I need an array because i can't find a way to render without mapping. Also yeah I am going to test out reducing the image size and optimizing. I have a bunch of images that have to be small. Do you have any recommendations to do so? thanks @Edper !

Answer (score 0):

So I deployed this and left it as is It seems like during development mode all png or jpg will be converted to webp hence the slow reload. So deploy it and check out its performance on Vercel just dont use webp cause next will convert that 2 .